# Testlink 1.9.4 Buzzilla interface xmlrpc

Tags: testing, xml-rpc, bugzilla

I'm trying to integrate Testlink 1.9.4 and Bugzilla by xmlrpc interface.
I went to the Issue Tracker Management in the Testlink GUI and confugures the params:

```
<issuetracker>
<username>USERNAME</username>
<password>PASSWORD</password>
<uribase>http://myBugzillaURL/</uribase>
</issuetracker>
```

I run a test, but when I try to add a bug the Testlink does not add anything.
It calls the URL `myIP/testlink/lib/execute/bugAdd.php` and returns the following:

If the bug ID exists:

```
object(stdClass)#152 (6) { ["IDHTMLString"]=> string(14) "5883 : " ["statusCode"]=> int(0) ["statusVerbose"]=> string(11) "UNCONFIRMED" ["statusHTMLString"]=> string(14) "[UNCONFIRMED] " ["summaryHTMLString"]=> string(18) "this is my summary" ["summary"]=> string(18) "this is my summary" }
```

If the bug ID does not exist:

```
object(stdClass)#152 (6) { ["IDHTMLString"]=> string(17) "1000000 : " ["statusCode"]=> int(0) ["statusVerbose"]=> NULL ["statusHTMLString"]=> string(3) "[] " ["summaryHTMLString"]=> NULL ["summary"]=> NULL }
```

I am not understanding why it is not working.
Testlink connects to Bugzilla but it does not add the bug information to the test case I ran.
Is there anyone with this working fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testelink 1.9.4 has a bug that causes Bugzilla to fail.
It is needed to delete 2 lines of code from the file `lib/issuetrackerintegration/bugzillaxmlrpcInterface.class.php`

Check it here http://gitorious.org/testlink-ga/testlink-code/commit/084429d478fa12cd2939c4c13287c4b7ba71bb51

Taken from http://mantis.testlink.org/view.php?id=5346

> Issue found there is a DIE() inside the checkid* method Give a look to
>   commit and change you code accordingly

Thank you fmat!