# Testlink 1.9.4 and Bugzilla 4.2.3 integration

Tags: testing, bugzilla, testlink

I have successfully installed TestLink 1.9.4 and Bugzilla 4.2.3 in Apache server on a Windows machine. I found out that in order to connect TestLink version 1.9.4 with any bug tracker you no longer need to make use of the `.cfg` file and therefore make use of the 'Issue tracker management' instead.

But TestLink documentation doesn't help, it contains older version details.

How do you integrate TestLink 1.9.4 with Bugzilla?

Answer (score 2):

After installing *TestLink 1.9.4* and run it for the first time, it asks you to create a Test Project. On that page you are invited to associate an Issue Tracker Integration but none is available to be chosen.

Ignore that and continue to create your Test Project. After creating it, on the main TestLink page look for the option "Issue Tracker Management". Create a new one and chose Bugzilla( Interface:xmlrpc) - this the the easiest one to setup in my opinion. Follow the configuration example and save.

Then go to the main page again and chose "Test Project Management". Edit the Test Project you created before and now you will have an Issue Tracker Integration to assign to the project (you Bugzilla xmlrpc interface).

The setup should end here but unfortunately TestLink 1.9.4 has a bug on the Bugzilla xmlrpc interface integration that keeps you from using it. To correct this bug follow these instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396750/testlink-1-9-4-buzzilla-interface-xmlrpc) and all you'll be fine. I am using it for over a month now.